# Slow 4g Network - Sometimes Signalr HubConnection.StartAync never returns or Sometimes Network unreachable exception is coming in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, signalr, signalr.client

We have a Xamarin Android app that uses Signalr for communication with the server. The app has a foreground service and it keeps a continuous signal-r connection. Sometimes, in a slow network when the connection drops, the app is not able to reestablish the connection with the server. Sometimes the startAsync never returns or sometimes the network is an unreachable exception is coming. But we notice that at the same time, other apps are able to connect with the server. Even the API calls in our app work. But the signal-r connection doesn't get established. To re-establish the connection, we need to turn OFF and turn ON the 4g connection.

```
public static async Task<SignalrConnection> NewConnection(string token, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = $"{ConfigService.TRANSFER_URL}";
                var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl(url, opts =>
                    {
                        opts.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
                    })
                    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
                    .Build();
                
                await connection.StartAsync(cancellationToken);

                var sc = new SignalrConnection(connection);
                return sc;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex1)
            {
                if (ex1.Message.Contains("401"))
                {
                    throw new NotAuthorizeException();
                }
                else
                    throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Message : Network is unreachable
StackTrace :   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ac] in <7fd014203845408d8ac08616d88f8f38>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00134] in <7fd014203845408d8ac08616d88f8f38>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in <7fd014203845408d8ac08616d88f8f38>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00089] in <7fd014203845408d8ac08616d88f8f38>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <7fd014203845408d8ac08616d88f8f38>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.AccessTokenHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00163] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009f] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in <7fd014203845408d8ac08616d88f8f38>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync (System.Uri url, System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00284] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008a] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0018e] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00139] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00092] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0011e] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d3] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000b3] in <d3cc4f3426ea47de89566d0665431af2>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001b6] in <d3cc4f3426ea47de89566d0665431af2>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00092] in <d3cc4f3426ea47de89566d0665431af2>:0
```

```
Message : WebSockets failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
StackTrace : 
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException
Message : Unable to connect to the remote server
StackTrace :   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsyncCore (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocketOptions options) [0x00385] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHandle.Managed.cs:150 
  at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d1] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ClientWebSocket.cs:157 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.DefaultWebSocketFactory (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.WebSocketConnectionContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x003da] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.StartAsync (System.Uri url, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00123] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartTransport (System.Uri connectUrl, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType transportType, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c5] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00531] in <d5c96e7f095e4a9ba210d5848b0716e1>:0 
System.OperationCanceledException
Message : The operation was canceled.
StackTrace :   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectSocketAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ec] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHandle.Managed.cs:187 
  at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectSocketAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002b5] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHandle.Managed.cs:202 
  at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsyncCore (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocketOptions options) [0x0008d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHandle.Managed.cs:97 
System.ObjectDisposedException
Message : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
StackTrace :   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:2896 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1207 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+<>c.<ConnectAsync>b__10_0 (System.IAsyncResult iar) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.Tasks.cs:141 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectSocketAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0016c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHandle.Managed.cs:178
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be useful for someone. Earlier I was creating new connections every time. But after starting to reuse the connection object, the problem has gone away. In a slow network, I just call connection.StartAsync in a loop until the connection gets established.